# Add documentation to custom methods (ScriptMethod)

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

A custom PowerShell script or function can be documented with a standard comment at the beginning of its body:

```
function wellDocumented {
   <#
       .SYNOPSIS
       A well documented function
       .DESCRIPTION
       "Be verbose in documentation" - someone
       .PARAMETER foo
        should be 42 or 15, but not more
    #>
    param( [int]$foo )
    <# ... #>
}
```

`Get-Help wellDocumented` returns some nice information then. But how can I document custom `ScriptMethod`s in custom objects? The following does not work:

```
$myClass | add-member -memType ScriptMethod -Name "Foo" -Value {
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
        Something - but brief
        .DESCRIPTION
        Something
    #>
    <# ... #>
}
```

Is there some standard way to document your ScriptMethods?

Comment: What is `$myClass` ?

Comment: I followed the approach of defining classes and making instances of them in http://powertoe.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/you-know-powershell-is-an-object-oriented-language-right/

Comment: I would most likely just write it as a C# module and use an XML help file. Not an answer, but a possible alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your script method as a separate function first (like you did with `wellDocumented`) then pass the function as the scriptblock:

```powershell
$myClass | add-member -memType ScriptMethod -Name "Foo" -Value ${function:wellDocumented}
```

You still can't call `Get-Help $myClass.Foo`, but you can call `Get-Help wellDocumented`.

In my testing I was not able to get help on a method.

Comment: But then a user of my class would have to look into the implementation to find out that he/she hast to `get-help wellDocumented` to find help - which is more cumbersome than just looking into the implementation and read the documentation there... Thanks for your answer though!